# nodejs imagemagick how to return text

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, gm

I'm stuck in the middle of the process of calculating the average color of an image via [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)'s subclass imagemagick. After resizing the image into a 1x1 image, I need to return the image information by "txt:-" so therefore im using the .out() command of gm. But now I don't know where and how to handle the callback ...

```
var gm     = require('gm').subClass({
  imageMagick: true
});

gm(IMAGEPATH).resize('1x1!').out('txt:-').... // how to get the string back ?
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. I'm having the same issue. I'm using `.command('convert')` but then looking to retrieve `out(':info')` but piping to `stream()` - It's returning the image data.

Answer (score 1):

i wasn't able to understand it properly let me know if i am wrong

You can try to save response to buffer and then read it's properties like below

```
var fs = require('fs'),
gm = require('gm').subClass({
    imageMagick: true
});

// output all available image properties
gm('20.png').resize(1, 1)
    .toBuffer('PNG', function(err, buffer) {
        gm(buffer, 'image.png').identify(function(err, data) {
            if (!err) console.log(data)
                console.log(data)
        });
    });
```

Comment: does .identify() return me the pixel information ? color ?

Comment: yup here's what i got
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/070ac932f654bbdb190a307a68379221

Comment: Thank you @harsh zalavadiya, this does solve the problem, but does not answer my question. I actually need to know, how you can run the comamnd "txt:-" and handle the callback.